Group streaks ending in False and apply forward / backward filling
I have a dataframe, where I want to forward / backward fill, based on a boolean series, df['condition'].
A single group consists of a streak of True values including the breaking False entry that separates a streak from the next one.
What I mean is very clear when looking at my dataframes. My input looks like this:
condition_values = [True, True, True, False, True, True, False, True,
                    True, False, True, True, True]
value_values = [0.1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
                np.nan, np.nan, 0.5, np.nan, 0.9, np.nan]

data = {'condition': condition_values,
        'value': value_values}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    condition  value
0        True    0.1
1        True    NaN
2        True    NaN
3       False    NaN
4        True    NaN
5        True    NaN
6       False    NaN
7        True    NaN
8        True    NaN
9       False    0.5
10       True    NaN
11       True    0.9
12       True    NaN

My desired output looks like this:
condition_values = [True, True, True, False, True, True, False, True, True, 
                    False, True, True, True]
value_values = [0.1,0.1, 0.1, 0.1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
                0.9, 0.9, 0.9]

data = {'condition': condition_values,
        'value': value_values}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

    condition  value
0        True    0.1
1        True    0.1
2        True    0.1
3       False    0.1
4        True    NaN
5        True    NaN
6       False    NaN
7        True    0.5
8        True    0.5
9       False    0.5
10       True    0.9
11       True    0.9
12       True    0.9

I have tried to make a bunch of dataframes, split by the Falses, ffill and bfill, and then re-concatenated. There has to be a faster way. I am very willing to take hints instead of the full solution - I'm trying to figure this out one way or another.

@mozway: I'd say that this is a partial duplicate at best, as the OP's first and main issue is with properly defining the groups (each False after a streak of True needs to be included in that group). Beyond that, the data sample (at least) is such that transform(first) can also be used to get the desired result, which is not true for the suggested duplicate.

You were quite close indeed! You can try as follows:
Option 1: ffill().bfill()
df['value'] = (
    df.groupby(
        df['condition'].shift().eq(0).cumsum()
        .where(df['condition']).ffill()
    )['value']
    .apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
    .droplevel(0)
)

Option 2: transform(first)
If you only have one value per group (as in your example), this can be done even simpler:
df['value'] = (
    df.groupby(
        df['condition'].shift().eq(0).cumsum()
        .where(df['condition']).ffill()
    )['value'].transform('first')
)

Output
    condition  value
0        True    0.1
1        True    0.1
2        True    0.1
3       False    0.1
4        True    NaN
5        True    NaN
6       False    NaN
7        True    0.5
8        True    0.5
9       False    0.5
10       True    0.9
11       True    0.9
12       True    0.9

Explanation

Start with Series.shift for df['condition'] and check Series.eq to 0 (as you did).

Now, chain Series.where to "reset" False rows to NaN and apply Series.ffill, thus adding them to the previous group.

Pass the result to df.groupby, select column 'value'.

Option 1: use groupby.apply to apply Series.ffill and Series.bfill to each group. In this case, you need to get rid of the prepended index level with df.droplevel before assignment to df['value'].

Option 2: if you only have 1 value, you can simply use groupby.transform and get groupby.first. With default setting, this will return the first non-NaN value.



very complete answer. Thank you.

I've been working on it some more.
I believe the answer actually lies with groupby.
 s = df.condition.shift(1).eq(0).cumsum()
 df['value2'] = df.groupby(s).value.ffill().bfill()

This isn't perfect yet but getting there.
Ok, the issue is that ffill().bfill() breaks groups because the second fill is working with series. Got it:
  df['value2'] = df.groupby(s).value.ffill()
  df['value2'] = df.groupby(s).value.bfill()

